# SSL_Accept fails, SSL_get_error returns 1

Tags: c, linux, security, ssl, openssl

I am new to SSL socket programming and my first task is to get the SSL server client to be working and understanding.

I have obtained the server and client sources floating on the web and compiled them against my openssl library (compiled from source).

When I start the server I am able to create a normal clientfd using accept system call, however SSL_accept fails.

```c
clientsocketfd = accept(serversocketfd, NULL, 0);
serverssl = SSL_new(ssl_server_ctx);
if(!serverssl)
{
    printf("Error SSL_new\n");
    return -1;
}
SSL_set_fd(serverssl, clientsocketfd);

if((ret = SSL_accept(serverssl))!= 1)
{
    printf("Handshake Error %d\n", SSL_get_error(serverssl, ret));
    return -1;
}
```

`SSL_accept` fails printing `Handshake error 1`.

Why is `SSL_accept` failing with error 1?

---

Server source:

```c
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--- main - create SSL socket server.                              ---*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main(int count, char *strings[])
{   SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    char *portnum;

    if ( count != 2 )
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <portnum>\n", strings[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    portnum = strings[1];
    SSL_library_init();
    ctx = InitServerCTX();                                                              /* initialize SSL */
    LoadCertificates(ctx, "newreq.pem", "newreq.pem");  /* load certs */
    server = OpenListener(atoi(portnum));                               /* create server socket */
    while (1)
    {   struct sockaddr_in addr;
        int len = sizeof(addr);
        SSL *ssl;

        int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);             /* accept connection as usual */
        printf("Connection: %s:%d\n",
                inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
        ssl = SSL_new(ctx);                                             /* get new SSL state with context */
        SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);                                                /* set connection socket to SSL state */
        Servlet(ssl);                                                                   /* service connection */
    }
    close(server);                                                                              /* close server socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);                                                                  /* release context */
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--- InitServerCTX - initialize SSL server  and create context     ---*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX(void)
{   SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();               /* load & register all cryptos, etc. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();                   /* load all error messages */
    method = SSLv3_server_method();             /* create new server-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);                  /* create new context from method */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}
```

The OpenSSL version and compilation options are as folows:

```
/usr/bin/openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: cc -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT 
-DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong 
-Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,
-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int 
-DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT 
-DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM 
-DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM 
-DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

Comment: Check all your return values.  How useful is that comment style of putting your comments way out to the right of your code?  Can you *see* those comments without having to play around with the scroll bar?  Commenting like that is a bad idea.  And how much time did you spend creating those pretty ASCII-art box comments?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, SSLv3 has been disabled in packages distributed with some Linux distros (e.g. Ubuntu 16.04):

> openssl (1.0.2g-1ubuntu1) xenial; urgency=medium
>
> - Merge with Debian, remaining changes.
>
>   - Disable SSLv3 without changing ABI:
>
>     - debian/patches/no-sslv3.patch: Disable SSLv3 without using the
>         no-ssl3-method option
>     - debian/rules: don't use no-ssl3-method, don't bump soname
>     - debian/patches/engines-path.patch: don't bump soname
>     - debian/patches/version-script.patch: don't bump soname
>     - debian/patches/soname.patch: removed
>     - debian/lib*: don't bump soname

Therefore you need to use another method:

```
method = SSLv3_server_method();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, I used ubuntu 14.04 and the code goes ahead past the error for the method creation.  I get an error during SSL_accept, although normal accept passes and a client connection fd is getting created, how can I solve this.

Comment: It doesn't matter which Ubuntu version you're using, it was disabled in Ubuntu's package of SSL v1.0.2g, which you've used, therefore you can get back to Ubuntu 16.04 and downgrade your package if you want. Or change SSL server method.

Answer (score 1):

The man page for [`SSL_accept`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_accept.html) states:

> If the underlying BIO is non-blocking, SSL_accept() will also return
>   when the underlying BIO could not satisfy the needs of SSL_accept() to
>   continue the handshake, indicating the problem by the return value -1.
>   In this case a call to SSL_get_error() with the return value of
>   SSL_accept() will yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE.
>   The calling process then must repeat the call after taking appropriate
>   action to satisfy the needs of SSL_accept()...

I believe that means your code should look something like:

```
while (1)
{
    int acc = SSL_accept(ssl);
    if (acc == 0)
    {
        /* Hard error */
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (acc == -1)
    {
        int err = SSL_get_error(ssl, ret);
        if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ)
        {
            /* Wait for data to be read */
        }
        else if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE)
        {
            /* Write data to continue */
        }
        else if (err == SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL || err == SSL_ERROR_SSL)
        {
            /* Hard error */
            exit(-1);
        }
        else if (err == SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN)
        {
            /* Same as error */
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* Continue */
        break;
    }
}
```

OpenSSL has sample code in `<openssl src>/apps/s_client.c` and `<openssl src>/apps/s_server.c`

Comment: s_client is a great place to start to understand what's going on with SSL errors